# Reference request: applications of topological quantum field theory to continuous-time dynamical systems.

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, topological-quantum-field-theory

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory):

> In dynamics, all continuous time dynamical systems, with and without noise, are Witten-type TQFTs and the phenomenon of the spontaneous breakdown of the corresponding topological supersymmetry encompasses such well-established concepts as chaos, turbulence, 1/f and crackling noises, self-organized criticality etc.

These are all very deep questions in continuous-time dynamics, and its somewhat surprising that TQFT has such a wide range of applications. Unfortunately, that wikipedia article doesn't include inline citations, so it isn't clear which source that information comes from. Could someone point to a textbook or review on the applications of TQFT to continuous-time dynamical systems?

Comment: Crossposted at: https://mathoverflow.net/q/332145/85967